# geofire returns duplicates keys when expanding radius in swift

Tags: swift, geofire

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling by expanding the radius of my `GeoFire` query by 5kms so I can get the next set of keys. But my `GeoFire` query is returning duplicates as it is picking up the keys found within the first 5kms in addition to the next 5kms so-on and so-on...

I was under the impression that it should only return the new keys found within the updated radius, **have I missed something?**

Console output showing duplicate keys found at 10kms then 15kms radius:

[image]

My `geoQuery`:

```
let geoQuery = GeoFire(firebaseRef: DB_BASE.child("venues-location")).query(at: CLLocation(), withRadius: 1)
```

My `fetchVenueNearby` function:

```
func fetchVenueNearby(deviceLocation: CLLocation, radius: Double, handler: @escaping (Venue) -> ()) {

        geoQuery.center = deviceLocation
        geoQuery.radius = radius

        geoQuery.observe(.keyEntered) { (key: String!, venueLocation: CLLocation!) in 

            print ("FOUND KEY: ", key) 

            self.REF_VENUES.child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in 

                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {

                    //parse snapshot code here….

                }//end if-let

            })//end observeSingleEvent

        }//end geofire query observe


    }//end func
```

This is my `loadMoreVenues` func currently used for testing my Geo Query

```
func loadMoreVenus() {

    radius += 5

    print("radius = \(radius)")


    DataService.run.fetchVenueNearby(deviceLocation: currentLocation, radius: radius) { (venue) in
        print("venue: \(venue.venueID)")
    }


}//end func
```

Comment: you need to filter out the already added  places

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the already existed  results.

As you request new result with new parameter that it **+5km**  it's going to return you a new result and you have to compare what already there and remove it from the result.

I don't know alot about `GeoFire` but however.

A better choice is to request based on the latest place you get as your starting point instead of the user current place to get the latest result without having to deal with filtering  them